# Skip on Type Mismatch

Tags: excel, vba, loops, error-handling, skip

on the "Value = " line there are instances in the loop where I will run into type mismatch or empty cells.

Could someone explain how I can use an error test to skip this step and continue my loop if there is an error in the data set ?

Thank you!

```
Sub ExpDate()

Dim bRow As Double
Dim tRow As Double
Dim lCol As Double
Dim fCol As Double
Dim ListRow As Double

Dim Value As Date

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Canadian")

bRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).row
tRow = 5
fCol = 7

Do While tRow <= bRow
    lCol = Cells(tRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Do While fCol <= lCol


        Value = Cells(tRow, fCol).Value

        ListRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row + 1
        Cells(ListRow, 1).Value = Value


    fCol = fCol + 1
    Loop

fCol = 7
tRow = tRow + 1
Loop


Range("A5:A1000").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 1), Header:=xlYes

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Having a date variable named `Value` is really not a great idea...

Comment: You should include the dot operator (.) inside the above when using a With block

Comment: Can't upvote @QHarr's comment enough so thought I'd repeat it.  As it is your `With...End With` is doing nothing - have another sheet active when you run the code and see the mess it makes of it.  Use `.Cells` and `.Range` to reference cells within the _Canadian_ worksheet inside the block.

Answer (score 2):

A few things.

You just need to check whether the cell contains a date.

Use `Long` for integer variables rather than `Double`.

Your With statement was redundant as you need to use dots in front of  the       range references - I have added them.

```
Sub ExpDate()

Dim bRow As Long
Dim tRow As Long
Dim lCol As Long
Dim fCol As Long
Dim ListRow As Long
Dim Value As Date

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Canadian")
    bRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
    tRow = 5
    fCol = 7

    Do While tRow <= bRow
        lCol = .Cells(tRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Do While fCol <= lCol
            If IsDate(.Cells(tRow, fCol).Value) Then
                ListRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                .Cells(ListRow, 1).Value = .Cells(tRow, fCol).Value
                fCol = fCol + 1
            End If
        Loop
        fCol = 7
        tRow = tRow + 1
    Loop
    .Range("A5:A1000").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 1), Header:=xlYes
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: It's my pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that your input looks like column `A` and you want to pass the dates to column `B`:

[image]

There are two problems, which should be taken into account - the cells in row 3 and row 5. Row 5 could be checked easily, as far as it is an error and `?IsError(Cells(5,1)` would return `True`. However, if one tries to check `?IsError(Cdate("K"))`, there would be a problem.

A quick way to fix it is a dedicated boolean function with `On Error Resume Next` in it, returning `True` if there is any specific error in the `CDate(value)` conversition:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim target As Range
    Dim myCell As Range
    Set target = Worksheets(1).Range("A1:A6")

    For Each myCell In target
        If IsCellDate(myCell) Then
            Dim someDate As Date
            someDate = myCell
            myCell.Offset(0, 1) = someDate
        End If
    Next

End Sub

Public Function IsCellDate(myData As Variant) As Boolean

    On Error Resume Next '- use this line really with caution!

    If IsError(CDate(myData)) Then
        IsCellDate = False
        Exit Function
    End If
    IsCellDate = True

End Function
```

Or you can use the `IsDate()` and avoid the custom function like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53173303/5448626).